# Finding sum of array of hash values in ruby

Tags: ruby

Finding sum of array of hash values in ruby throws error

```
parsed_response = [
  {"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"1.19782496", "available"=>"1.19782496"},
  {"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}
]

parsed_response.map { |h| h["available"].to_f }.sum
```

This throws the following error:

```
undefined method `sum' for [1.19782496, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

How should I change my code?

Comment: I can't find where you call `sum`?

Comment: working for me: `parsed_response.map { |h| h["available"].to_f }.sum
 => 1.19782496`

Comment: You've converted them to floats with to_f in your code, but in the error it looks like you haven't - they're still strings (which can't be summed).  Is that error definitely caused by the line of code you've put in your question?

Comment: Jeff, in future please simplify examples as much as you can. Here I think you could have had just two keys, one being `"available"`. Also, it would be easier to read if you formatted the code so that horizontal scrolling is not required. Here, each hash in `parsed_response` (with fewer key-value pairs) would fit nicely on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you're using just Ruby. You can try this(as there's no `sum` method for Array in Ruby):

```
parsed_response.inject(0){|sum, response| sum = sum+response['available'].to_f }
#=> 1.19782496
```

If you're using Rails, then it has [`sum`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) method in `Enumerable` which is included by `Array`, can be used like so:

```
parsed_response.map { |h| h["available"].to_f }.sum #=> 1.19782496
```

Comment: I prefer the first as it avoids the creation of the temporary array produced by `map`. +1

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) is a method which doesn't exist in vanilla Ruby. Rather, it's an extension loaded as part of the [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) web development framework.

In vanilla Ruby, a reasonable substitute is [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```
parsed_response = [
  {"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"1.19782496", "available"=>"1.19782496"},
  {"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}
]

parsed_response.map { |h| h["available"].to_f }.reduce(:+)
#=> 1.19782496
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

with active support, `sum` should be defined:

```
require 'active_support/all'
parsed_response = [{"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"1.19782496", "available"=>"1.19782496"}, {"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}, {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}, {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}, {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}, {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}]
parsed_response.map { |h| h["available"].to_f }.sum
# => 1.19782496
```

without active support, `sum` is not defined and you should use `inject(:+)` instead:

```
parsed_response = [{"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"1.19782496", "available"=>"1.19782496"}, {"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}, {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}, {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}, {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}, {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}]
parsed_response.map { |h| h["available"].to_f }.inject(:+)
# => 1.19782496
```

If you forget `to_f` convertion as your error suggests, you will concatenate all the strings:

```
["1.19782496", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"].inject(:+)
# => 1.197824960.00.00.00.00.0
```

Comment: `sum` is part of [`Enumerable`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum) in `Rails` and `Array` class include `Enumerable`

Comment: in rails indeed... not in ruby

Comment: please indicate this in the reply.

Comment: He's tagged the question with `ruby-on-rails` so i think it's fair to assume we can use Rails-specific code.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, I'm not sure you should assume that (though the Rails tag has since been removed). I see lots of questions with Rails tags that have nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: Well, if the questioner tags a question with Rails, and gets some rails-specific info as a result, then that's their own fault.

Answer (score 0):

A super simple way to achieve this:

```
result = 0.0
parsed_response.each do |item|
  result += item["available"].to_f
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
parsed_response = [
  {"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"1.19782496", "available"=>"1.19782496"},
  {"type"=>"trading", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"deposit", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"btc", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"},
  {"type"=>"exchange", "currency"=>"usd", "amount"=>"0.0", "available"=>"0.0"}
]

parsed_response.collect { |a| a["available"].to_f }.inject(:+)
#=> 1.19782496
```